# Masking a mixed data type matrix in Python

Tags: python

I want to create an index of a huge amount of data files I have. The index should contain different values (String, Float and Int), as columns. Each row should represent one file.
For this I could use a list. 
Now, however, I would like to create a boolean mask with a criterion for one of the columns

```
   Index = [[4., 8., 3., 5., 0., 10.],   #some value
            [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8],          #starting time
            ["file1", "file1", "file2", "file2", "file2", "file3"],   #location file
            [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]           #ID in location file
           ]
```

So I want to for example, say Index[where Index[0] < 5. and Index[1] > 3] and get "location file"+"ID". I know I can do masking operations like this in numpy, but I cannot have mixed data types in np.arrays.

What is an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have to store these different types in a single array? Why can you not have 3 1-D arrays and mask the 3rd with indices from the first two?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question!

Comment: What do you expect your output to be with `Index[0] < 5 and Index[1] > 3`?

Comment: FWIW I'd probably use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) for this sort of thing, although you could do it using `numpy` and `dtype=object`.  (Or structured arrays, although I find they tend to be more trouble than they're worth.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you were expecting, but this will output tuples of the elements in `Index[2]` and `Index[3]` that you *seem* to want.

```
>>> def mask(data, *criteria):
    toRet = []
    for i in range(len(data[0])):
        for index, predicate in criteria:
            if not predicate(data[index][i]):
                break
        else:
            toRet.append((data[2][i], data[3][i]))
    return toRet
>>> mask(Index, (0, lambda x: x <5), (1, lambda x: x > 3))
[('file2', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist on using a single array, I would heed @DSM's advice and use pandas.  For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: %paste
Index = [[4., 8., 3., 5., 0., 10.],   #some value
            [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8],          #starting time
            ["file1", "file1", "file2", "file2", "file2", "file3"],   #location file
            [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]           #ID in location file
           ]

## -- End pasted text --
In [3]: x = pd.DataFrame(zip(*Index), columns=['sv', 'time', 'file', 'id'])
In [4]: x
Out[4]: 
   sv  time   file  id
0   4     1  file1   1
1   8     1  file1   2
2   3     1  file2   1
3   5     2  file2   2
4   0     4  file2   3
5  10     8  file3   1

[6 rows x 4 columns]
In [5]: x.query('(sv < 5) & (time > 3)')
Out[5]: 
   sv  time   file  id
4   0     4  file2   3

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

You can also use pure python instead of `DataFrame.query()` (which requires pandas > 13.0):

```
In [6]: x[(x.sv < 5) & (x.time > 3)]
Out[6]: 
   sv  time   file  id
4   0     4  file2   3

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```